# Proving that a topology is Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathbb N := \{1,2,\cdots\}$ and $\mathbb N_0 := \mathbb N \cup \{0\}$. Let $\mathcal B := \{U_{a,b}: a,b\in \mathbb N \}$ where 
$$
U_{a,b} = \{a+bn: n \in \mathbb N_0 \text{ and } (a,b) = 1\}.
$$ 
I have proven that $\mathcal B$ is a basis for a topology $\tau$ on $\mathbb N$. Now I want to show that $\tau$ is Hausdorff. So let $a,a' \in \mathbb N$ with $a \neq a'$. I want to find $b,b' \in \mathbb N$ s.t. $(a,b) = (a',b') = 1$ and $U_{a,b} \cap U_{a',b'} = \emptyset$. But I could not find a criterium on $b$ and $b'$. s.t. the intersection is empty. Maybe we can use that  $(a,b) = 1 = \alpha a + \beta b$ for some $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: If you choose $b = b'$, it is easy to see whether the intersection is empty. (And choosing the right $b$ makes it empty.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $p$ is a prime distinct from $a$ and $a'$ and $p$ does not divide $a'-a$, then $\{a+np\}\cap\{a'+np\}=\emptyset$.

Now you just need to show that every pair $\{a,a'\}$ has a $p$ which does not divide $a'-a$.